# Можно совместить Google AdSense и Яндекс РСЯ?

Tags: реклама, google-adsense, встроенная-реклама, рся-яндекс

По правилам Google AdSense и Рекламной сети Яндекса, можно вставить блоки обеих рекламных сетей на одной странице?

PS. Заметил что много сайтов так делают, но знаю что раньше Google AdSense был против этого.

Comment: __Google AdSense был против этого__ - надо просто не обращать внимание на их пожелания, это самый правильный подход. :)

Comment: не знаю если это только "пожелание"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формально - это не запрещено, но в то же время вызывает целый ряд трудностей. Одна из них - это увеличение площади, которую занимает реклама на сайте, без существенного увеличения эффективности. То есть - если вы будете показывать 6 рекламных объявлений там, где ранее показывали 3, большего количества кликов по рекламе это не принесет - скорее эффект будет обратным. Кроме того, вполне логично показывать пользователям, пришедшим из результатов поиска Google, именно рекламу Google AdSense, а пользователям из Яндекса - блок Яндекс.Директа. Используя такой подход вполне можно разметить оба блока на одном месте и с некоторой долей вероятности увеличить доход со своего сайта без снижения эффективности рекламных блоков.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite.ucoz.ru/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var gcode = 'Заменить на код от Google'; 
var ycode = 'Заменить на код от Yandex'; 
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2+1); 

if (document.referrer !== "") { 
var re= new RegExp("^http[s]?:\/\/(www\.|)([^\/]*)\/([^\?]*)", "i"); 
var domen_search = document.referrer.match(re); 
var refdomain=RegExp.$2; 
var date = new Date( new Date().getTime() + 60*1000 ); 

if ($.cookie('refdomain')) { 
$.cookie('refdomain', $.cookie('refdomain'), { expires: date, path: "/" }); 
} 
else { 
$.cookie('refdomain', refdomain, { expires: date, path: "/" }); 
} 
if ($.cookie('refdomain').match(/^google\./)) { document.write(gcode); } 
else if ($.cookie('refdomain').match(/^yandex\./)) { document.write(ycode); } 
else { if (rand==1) {document.write(gcode);} else {document.write(ycode);} } 
} 
else 
{ if (rand==1) {document.write(gcode);} else {document.write(ycode);} } 
</script>
```

Принцип работы этого кода прост. В случае, если пользователь перешел на сайт с Google или Yandex - показываем соответствующий рекламный блок, запоминая источник перехода в cookie. При перемещении пользователя по сайту проверяем cookie и показываем нужный блок. В случае, если пользователь перешел на сайт из других источников, либо зашел напрямую (введя адрес в браузере) - показываем рекламные блоки от Google и Yandex в случайном порядке.

Для того чтобы данный код работал корректно, разместите его в нужное место в шаблоне вашего сайта, например, в одном из глобальных блоков. Участки кода, выделенные жирным шрифтом, необходимо заменить на собственные.

Comment: Отличный подход. Только сделаю на PHP, удобнее будет.